# How to enable page numbers without affecting footers/headers

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting

I am trying to put page numbers on the right hand side on the bottom of the page, but it keeps moving the text of the footer making it off center.

Anyone know how to keep this from happening?

Also, does anyone know how to enable total pages like 3/4. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).range.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter 'Centers Header'
.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).range.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("C:\Users\pgates\Desktop\ Logo Swoops cropped 2.JPG") 'Calls for image header'
.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).range.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter 'Centers Footer'
.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).range.Text = " rwetwet" & vbCr & "wetrwet" & vbCr & "Phone:wertttr"
.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add
```

Comment: There is no such thing in Microsoft Word as "enabling" page numbers. You can design your footer freely. It seems you look for something like in Microsoft Excel or PowerPoint but it just works different in Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in Microsoft Word as "enabling" page numbers. You can design your footer freely. It seems you look for something like in Microsoft Excel or PowerPoint but it just works different in Microsoft Word.

Personally I would

- **insert a table** into the footer area with two or three columns
- and a **transparent border** to it

So you'll be able to enter your page numbers on the right side, while your other text in the footer stays on the left side (or middle depending on columns).

```
 ___________________ ________________________ ___________
|_Your footer text__|_Center part if needed__|_Page X/Y__|
```

**Update**

Have a look at your other question. I've put an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45388748/1306012) there.

Comment: Is this your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336656/vba-format-different-line-image-text-in-footer?noredirect=1#comment77666778_45336656 ?

Comment: No it should actually help you on this question. But since you've some related questions you can also use it as an answer for your other question ;-)