# How to insert page footer with page numbers, file path and image?

Tags: vba, image, text, ms-word, footer

[image]I'm trying to format the footer so it has the page # (x out of y) on the top right of the footer, and  then the image centered below. I ended up writing an algorithm for the page # and then used inlineshapes to insert the image above.  The problem is the text is below the image and the image is not centered. Any help would be appreciated.

```
.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).range.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter 'Centers Header'
.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).range.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("X:\EQP\Residential Maintenance Agreement\Archived RMA templates\AA Logo Swoops cropped 2.JPG") 'Calls for image header'
.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).range.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter 'Centers Footer'
.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).range.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("X:\EQP\Residential Maintenance Agreement\Footer Template.PNG")
With wdapp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(1).range.Paragraphs(1)
    .range.InsertAfter vbCr & "Page "
    Set r = .range
    E = .range.End
    r.Start = E
    .range.Fields.Add r, wdFieldPage
    .range.InsertAfter " of "
    E = .range.End
    r.Start = E
    .range.Fields.Add r, wdFieldNumPages
    .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    '.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    '.range.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("X:\EQP\Residential Maintenance Agreement\Footer Template.PNG")
End With
```

Comment: Can you provide a little drawing how the image should be placed? Should it be centered of the page or centered below the text "page x out of y" ? How big should the picture be? I'm interested why you do this in VBA?

Comment: I added a picture. I just want the the image at the bottom of the document. I believe it doesn't need to be re-scaled. I do it to format documents for a company from excel to word..It just saves time having the entire document automated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Philip. I get the idea now. I'm still interested on the size of the picture. It influences where to place the page and file path. Can you provide the height of the pic in Centimeters?

Comment: about 3cm perhaps

Comment: Did the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45388748/1306012) help you?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out something. Its bigger then I thought it would become. I sure it gets you started with what you want to reach.

There was some help involved from experts-exchange.com with their solution on
"[VBA to insert a modified Page x of y in a Word Footer](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23467589/VBA-to-insert-a-modified-Page-x-of-y-in-a-Word-Footer.html#discussion)". I've mentiond it in the code where I use it to convert test into fields.

As mentioned in your other question "[How to enable page numbers without affecting footers/headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45353009/1306012)" I follow the approach to use tables with empty borders. They allow you to place content very exact.
That's why the code below will insert a table with three columns:

```
 ___________________ ________________________ ___________
|_Your footer text__|_Center part if needed__|_Page X/Y__|
```

Below find the code. The main method `InsertFooter` you'll want to call from your code. It will do what you desire:

```
Sub InsertFooter()

Dim footer As HeaderFooter
Dim footerRange As range
Dim documentSection As Section
Dim currentView As View
Dim footerTable As table
Dim pictureShape As Shape

On Error GoTo MyExit

' Disable updating to prevent flickering
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each documentSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
    For Each footer In documentSection.Footers
        If footer.Index = wdHeaderFooterPrimary Then
            Set footerRange = footer.range
            ' add table to footer
            Set footerTable = AddTableToFooter(footerRange)
            ' Make table border transparent
            SetTableTransparentBorder footerTable
            ' Insert page X out of Y into third column in table
            InsertPageNumbersIntoTable footerTable
            ' Insert file path
            InsertFilePathIntoTable footerTable
            ' Add picture to footer
            AddPictureToFooter footerRange, "C:\Pictures\happy.jpg", 3
        End If
    Next footer
Next documentSection

MyExit:
' Enable updating again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenRefresh

End Sub

Sub AddPictureToFooter(range As range, filePath As String, pictureHeightInCm As Single)
    Set pictureShape = range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=filePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True).ConvertToShape
    pictureShape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapFront
    pictureShape.height = CentimetersToPoints(pictureHeightInCm)
    pictureShape.Top = 0
End Sub

Sub InsertPageNumbersIntoTable(tableToChange As table)
    ' Attention no error handling done!

    ' inserts "Page {page} of {pages}" into the third column of a table
    Dim cellRange As range
    Set cellRange = tableToChange.Cell(1, 3).range
    cellRange.InsertAfter "Page { PAGE } of { NUMPAGES }"
    TextToFields cellRange
End Sub


' Credits go to
' https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23467589/VBA-to-insert-a-modified-Page-x-of-y-in-a-Word-Footer.html#discussion
Sub TextToFields(rng1 As range)
    Dim c As range
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim rng2 As range
    Dim lFldStarts() As Long

    Set rng2 = rng1.Duplicate
    rng1.Document.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True

    For Each c In rng1.Characters
        DoEvents
        Select Case c.Text
            Case "{"
                ReDim Preserve lFldStarts(f)
                lFldStarts(f) = c.Start
                f = f + 1
            Case "}"
                f = f - 1
                If f = 0 Then
                    rng2.Start = lFldStarts(f)
                    rng2.End = c.End
                    rng2.Characters.Last.Delete '{
                    rng2.Characters.First.Delete '}
                    Set fld = rng2.Fields.Add(rng2, , , False)
                    Set rng2 = fld.Code
                    TextToFields fld.Code
                End If
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next c
    rng2.Expand wdStory
    rng2.Fields.Update
    rng1.Document.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
End Sub

Sub InsertFilePathIntoTable(tableToChange As table)
    ' Attention no error handling done!

    ' inserts "Page {page} of {pages}" into the third column of a table
    Dim cellRange As range
    Set cellRange = tableToChange.Cell(1, 1).range
    cellRange.InsertAfter "{ FILENAME \p }"
    TextToFields cellRange
End Sub

Sub SetTableTransparentBorder(tableToChange As table)
    tableToChange.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    tableToChange.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    tableToChange.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    tableToChange.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    tableToChange.Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    tableToChange.Borders(wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    tableToChange.Borders(wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
End Sub

Function AddTableToFooter(footerRange As range) As table
    Dim footerTable As table
    Set footerTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(range:=footerRange, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)
    ' Algin third column to right
    footerTable.Cell(1, 3).range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    Set AddTableToFooter = footerTable
End Function
```