# vba insert name of file w path to word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word, footer

I want to be able to insert the  file name along with the path of the active word document into the footer of the word document. Any help would be great!

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=24

Comment: How to I use NormalTemplate or AutoTextEntries? I've been using the activedocument expression. Also not sure about the placement "Where:=_"

Comment: Look at my answer on your other question "[How to insert page footer with page numbers, file path and image?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45388748/1306012)".

It seems you asked for every step a single question without any intention to try to solve it yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA update filename and path upon saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356821/vba-update-filename-and-path-upon-saving)