# VBA update filename and path upon saving

Tags: vba, ms-word, filenames

I've tried using the following codes below, but none will give me an active field that will update upon saving. **I want the file path and name**. Maybe you can help. Thanks.

`ActiveDocument.Name` - gives the name of the document, without path information.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say you want the file path and name, and then proceed to say that `ActiveDocument.FullName` gives you that. Am I missing something?

Comment: I edited it to make a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As @braX says

Use `FullName` to get the file name and path.
Note `FullName` will only contain the file path AFTER you have saved the document once!

```
' Saved
ActiveDocument.FullName ' -> C:\Documents\Doc1.docx

' Unsaved
ActiveDocument.FullName ' -> Document2
```

use `Name` to get the file name only

```
ActiveDocument.Name ' -> Doc1.docx
```